# How to chain several actions using MBProgressHUD?

Tags: iphone, mbprogresshud

Basically I have 3 steps:

1. I need to prepare the data to be sent to the server. This takes some time.
2. After preparing the data, I have to send it to the server - this also takes a while.
3. I wait for the response from server that everything is OK.

I was thinking of using MBProgressHUD for each of these actions - I show hud, and use the `showWhileExecuting` method. Then when I hide hud in that code I call the next action, and show hud again.

In theory this should work, but is this the way this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to not depend on MBProgressHUD. You should use it as a feedback element for the user, not as an operation manager.

You could use a NSOperationQueue, for example, and just notify the hud to update its data/status in each iteration.

Of course, you could use it like you said, but does not seems clean to me (programatically).

Comment: I see. But how would NSOperationQueue deal with server response? For first 2 events, i can put them in queue, but for third i have to wait for server to respond to take appropriate action.

Comment: I see...then check this link http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/

Answer (score 1):

i get the frist Action at button clicked,i use this :

```
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

        [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];


        // Regiser for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
        HUD.delegate = self;

        // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
        [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(DNS_info) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

and then 2 button clicked , get the action ,like this :

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

        [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];
//        HUD.dimBackground = NO;

        // Regiser for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
        HUD.delegate = self;

        // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
        [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(whois) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

i think, this is help to you.